# Make panes fixed with vertical scrollbar when screen scrolling main section

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

- three panes
- one main section
- when you vertically scroll down on the main section (with screen scrollbar) then the individual panes (which also have their own vertical scrollbar) should remain fixed (`position: fixed`) with vertical scrollbar each - How to accomplish? Adding `fixed` to each of the pane divs, makes them overlap eachother and does not work.

```
<div className="grid h-screen grid-cols-[20vw_20vw_20vw_100vw] overflow-x-scroll">
  <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-yellow-400 text-50xl">PANE*1*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-green-500 text-50xl">PANE*2*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-blue-300 text-50xl">PANE*3*Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div className="text-50xl">
    <main>*MAIN*Lorem ipsum</main>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]